# Transformers Victory toyline - was there a God Ginrai toy?

Tags: transformers

I'm aware that there was a Ginrai and Godbomber toy for the Masterforce toyline, but was there a re-release or similar for Victory? And if there was, did God Ginrai come with the sword he uses in the show?

I don't believe there was, but I'm hoping somebody who knows the Japanese toyline might be able to confirm.

Comment: That said, I'm *pretty* certain that there was a God Ginrai toy, but that it didn't include the sword. I won't have time to properly research it until tonight though.

Answer (score 1):

According to [TFWiki](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/God_Ginrai#Super-God_Masterforce) the Super Ginrai and the Godbomber toys can be combined to form God Ginrai. The two of them were sold separately and together as a gift set. But I don't see a mention of his sword.

> Super Ginrai was also sold in a gift set with Godbomber, who can
>   interact with Ginrai in several ways. Trailer-mode Godbomber can hook
>   up either directly to Ginrai's cab or to the back of Ginrai's own
>   trailer and be towed along behind him, while any of Ginrai's weapons
>   can plug into the holes in Godbomber's wings and chassis. Most
>   prominently, of course, Godbomber diseassembles into various component
>   parts that combine with Super Ginrai to form God Ginrai. Godbomber's
>   legs become boots known as "God Legs", to which Ginrai's Particle Beam
>   Cannons attach; his chest and wings form the "God Wing" backpack; his
>   arms clip over the top of Ginrai's own as the "God Punch"; and his
>   back becomes a chromed chestplate called the "God Breast", into the
>   top of which the spring-loaded, missile-firing "God Cannon" plugs. The
>   toy also features a secondary, lesser combination referred to as the
>   "God Breaster", which involves attaching the God Breast to Super
>   Ginrai, and plugging Godbomber's wings into his arms.

Comment: In Masterforce he doesn't have a sword, but he does in Victory. As he was a popular character at the time I thought they may have re-released him and - to match the TV show - given him a sword.

Comment: @VictorySaber - Doesn't seem like they did it seems.